# About Android View Touch event

Tags: android, view, touch

I met a very strange question when I studied the Android View Touch event. I have a layout in below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And I added touch listener to the textview and the linearlayout. As below:

```
private final static String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

LinearLayout llMain;
TextView tv1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    llMain = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_main);
    tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);
    llMain.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    Log.d(TAG, "Layout: Down");
                    return true;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    Log.d(TAG, "Layout: UP");
                    return false;
                default:
                    return false;
            }
        }
    });
    tv1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    Log.d(TAG, "TextView: Down");
                    return false;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    Log.d(TAG, "TextView: UP");
                    return false;
                default:
                    return false;
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            Log.d(TAG, "Activity: Down");
            return true;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            Log.d(TAG, "Activity: UP");
            return true;
    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

My problem is: when I pressed the textview, the order of the events that executed is: "TextView: Down" -> "TextView: UP" -> Activity: Up. Why the linearlayout's onTouch Method is not executed?

Answer (score 0):

<s>Because you clicks TextView, the priority will be TextView, after that layout cover. I think this is very normal. Could you post the code having  **Activity: Up**</s>

I search and found the answer like that:
If you return false, the next listener handles the event. If it returns true, the event is consumed by your listener and not sent to the next method.

Ex:
if you set `tv1` with `ACTION_DOWN` and `ACTION_UP`, return true -> it will don't send any event outside, so linear or activity cannot get the event.
And you change to false to see the changes.